# Best way to interpolate triangle surface using 3 positions and normals for ray tracing

Tags: c++, graphics, geometry, raytracing

I am working on conventional Whitted ray tracing, and trying to interpolate surface of hitted triangle as if it was convex instead of flat.
The idea is to treat triangle as a parametric surface `s(u,v)` once the barycentric coordinates `(u,v)` of hit point `p` are known.
This surface equation should be calculated using triangle's positions `p0, p1, p2` and normals `n0, n1, n2`.
The hit point itself is calculated as

```
p = (1-u-v)*p0 + u*p1 + v*p2;
```

I have found three different solutions till now.

**Solution 1. Projection**

The first solution I came to. It is to project hit point on planes that come through each of vertexes `p0, p1, p2` perpendicular to corresponding normals, and then interpolate the result.

```
vec3 r0 = p0 + dot( p0 - p, n0 ) * n0;
vec3 r1 = p1 + dot( p1 - p, n1 ) * n1;
vec3 r2 = p2 + dot( p2 - p, n2 ) * n2;
p = (1-u-v)*r0 + u*r1 + v*r2;
```

**Solution 2. Curvature**

Suggested in a paper of Takashi Nagata "Simple local interpolation of surfaces using normal vectors" and discussed in question "Local interpolation of surfaces using normal vectors", but it seems to be overcomplicated and not very fast for real-time ray tracing (unless you precompute all necessary coefficients). Triangle here is treated as a surface of the second order.

**Solution 3. Bezier curves**

This solution is inspired by Brett Hale's answer. It is about using some interpolation of the higher order, cubic Bezier curves in my case.
E.g., for an edge `p0p1` Bezier curve should look like

```
B(t) = (1-t)^3*p0 + 3(1-t)^2*t*(p0+n0*adj) + 3*(1-t)*t^2*(p1+n1*adj) + t^3*p1,
```

where `adj` is some adjustment parameter.

Computing Bezier curves for edges `p0p1` and `p0p2` and interpolating them gives the final code:

```
float u1 = 1 - u;
float v1 = 1 - v;
vec3 b1 = u1*u1*(3-2*u1)*p0 + u*u*(3-2*u)*p1 + 3*u*u1*(u1*n0 + u*n1)*adj;
vec3 b2 = v1*v1*(3-2*v1)*p0 + v*v*(3-2*v)*p2 + 3*v*v1*(v1*n0 + v*n2)*adj;
float w = abs(u-v) < 0.0001 ? 0.5 : ( 1 + (u-v)/(u+v) ) * 0.5;
p = (1-w)*b1 + w*b2;
```

Alternatively, one can interpolate between three edges:

```
float u1 = 1.0 - u;
float v1 = 1.0 - v;
float w = abs(u-v) < 0.0001 ? 0.5 : ( 1 + (u-v)/(u+v) ) * 0.5;
float w1 = 1.0 - w;
vec3 b1 = u1*u1*(3-2*u1)*p0 + u*u*(3-2*u)*p1 + 3*u*u1*( u1*n0 + u*n1 )*adj;
vec3 b2 = v1*v1*(3-2*v1)*p0 + v*v*(3-2*v)*p2 + 3*v*v1*( v1*n0 + v*n2 )*adj;
vec3 b0 = w1*w1*(3-2*w1)*p1 + w*w*(3-2*w)*p2 + 3*w*w1*( w1*n1 + w*n2 )*adj;
p = (1-u-v)*b0 + u*b1 + v*b2;
```

Maybe I messed something in code above, but this option does not seem to be very robust inside shader.

**P.S.** The intention is to get more correct origins for shadow rays when they are casted from low-poly models. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0if7.png) you can find the resulted images from test scene. Big white numbers indicates number of solution (zero for original image).

**P.P.S.** I still wonder if there is another efficient solution which can give better result.

Comment: After some investigation, I decided to accept Patrik H's advise to use scenes with more detailed model instead (alongside with solution 1 if needed).

Comment: I can confirm that from the methods, the first one is working. The others don't produce the expected result. I've also implemented PN tessellation which gives result similar to 1, but at much bigger cost. Most renderers seems to handle this by using huge shadow bias though, but it may cause light leaking. So I can conclude that there is not perfect solution, and even though the issue is less visible with subdivision and soft lights, it's still there to some extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping triangles 'flat' has many benefits and simplifies several stages required during rendering. Approximating a higher order surface on the other hand introduces quite significant tracing overhead and requires adjustments to your BVH structure.

When the geometry is being treated as a collection of facets on the other hand, the shading information can still be interpolated to achieve smooth shading while still being very efficient to process.

There are adaptive tessellation techniques which approximate the limit surface ([OpenSubdiv](http://graphics.pixar.com/opensubdiv/docs/subdivision_surfaces.html) is a great example). [Pixar's Photorealistic RenderMan](https://renderman.pixar.com/view/renderman) has a long history using subdivision surfaces. When they switched their rendering algorithm to path tracing, they've also introduced a pretessellation step for their subdivision surfaces. This stage is executed right before rendering begins and builds an adaptive triangulated approximation of the limit surface. This seems to be more efficient to trace and tends to use less resources, especially for the high-quality assets used in this industry.

So, to answer your question. I think the most efficient way to achieve what you're after is to use an adaptive subdivision scheme which spits out triangles instead of tracing against a higher order surface.

Comment: I do keep triangles flat and don't want to change their actual geometry. This interpolation is needed only to compute origin of the shadow rays for simple low-poly models like spheres. Without this, the shadows on a model look like stairs, since they recreate the shape of its primitives.

Comment: if you change the hitpoint, your triangles aren't flat anymore which is what I meant above.
Yes, this is a common problem present in most renderers, especially along the shadow terminator from small light sources (hard shadows). Usually, the tessellation of the geometry is increased until the problem goes away.
You could try adjusting your ray epsilon (shadow bias) before tracing back to the light, maybe that'll help smoothing the transition across triangle edges.

Comment: I have linked two images to this question. Don't think that adjusting ray epsilon could help, because it will result in the same flat surface which lies slightly above triangle. Maybe using models with more polygons could help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think you're giving this issue too much priority because you're using delta lights. Once you're using lights with finite area, the problem should be less prominent, especially once you're using denser geometry.
For the ray epsilon, you could use the smooth normal as bias direction instead of the geometric normal.

Comment: What is the difference between smooth normal and geometric normal? If geometric normal is the one derived from cross product, I don't use it at all.

Comment: yeah sorry, the geometric normal is the normal of the plane spanned by the vertices of the triangle.
when shooting transmission (shadow) rays, you can either apply a bias towards the light, in direction of the geometric normal (to prevent self intersections) or in direction of the smooth normal (prevent self intersections and smooth transitions).
So, do you bias towards the light or in direction of the smooth normal at the moment?

Comment: Towards smoothed normal.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Sunday describes an [algorithm](http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html) that calculates the barycentric coordinates on the triangle once the ray-plane intersection has been calculated. The point lies inside the triangle if:
`(s >= 0) && (t >= 0) && (s + t <= 1)`

You can then use, say, `n(s, t) = nu * s + nv * t + nw * (1 - s - t)` to interpolate a normal, as well as the point of intersection, though `n(s, t)` will not, in general, be normalized, even if `(nu, nv, nw)` are. You might find higher order interpolation necessary. [PN-triangles](http://alex.vlachos.com/graphics/CurvedPNTriangles.pdf) were a similar hack for visual appeal rather than mathematical precision. For example, true rational quadratic Bezier triangles can describe conic sections.

Comment: Does PN-triangles always require additional geometry tesselation? About another option, I have tried Bezier interpolation just now. It gives quite different result, but does not seem to be robust inside shader. The first approach with projection works better in my case.